# Grails. How to send a request to my DB too see changes

Tags: html, mysql, grails

How can i send a request to my DB, mySql, then check if there are changes so that i can refresh a `div` if there are changes?

-EDIT-

This is my code. It just auto refreshes the load function every 5s so that it will apply new  changes to the table. I dont know how to send a request to my DB to see changes.

```
<div id="updateThis">
    Loading........
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function refresh(){ 
        setInterval(function(){refresh()},5000);
        $('#updateThis').load('${createLink(controller:'table', action:'loadTables')}');

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Question can be more specific and at least with a sample that has been tried.

Comment: Can you add some part of your code to make your question more clear?

Comment: The question is still a little vague.  Are you asking about how to determine what data has changed between two time points in MySQL (change data capture) or simply how to update the DOM with DB changes retrieved from your Grails controller?

Comment: @dspies what my code is doing is the latter of your question. I think it would be better if I determine what data has changed between two time points in MySQL (change data capture) just as you said

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on the size of your system.

**'Enterprise'** - look at [Flexviews](http://flexviews.sourceforge.net/flexcdc.html) and/or [LinkedIn's Data Bus](http://engineering.linkedin.com/data-replication/open-sourcing-databus-linkedins-low-latency-change-data-capture-system).  If neither of those work for you, you should probably look for topics/tools related to Data Warehouse ETL with MySQL, since a large portion of the ETL process is determine efficient ways to extract changed data.  For instance, you could look at JasperSoft ETL Pro or [Talend Open Studio](http://www.talend.com/products/talend-open-studio) which has a number of tools to build a custom ETL process.

**'Basic'** - look at either adding timestamps to the tables in question and then querying for records with a timestamp value greater than the last time you checked (downside: no record of deletes) or add triggers to the database that record changes in data.

Also, if this system is large, you may want to look at pushing the changes via websockets or the like since polling every 5 seconds for changes is not going to scale well.  There are a number of articles and Grails plugins ([Atmosphere](http://grails.org/plugins/tag/websocket) and [Events Push](http://grails.org/plugin/events-push) to name a couple) on the topic.